# Replacing parameters in DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

How can I prevent SQL injection in this code using command.CommandText attribute to replace input parameters?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            sb.Append("DealClassification LIKE '%@Deal%' ");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deal", textBox1.Text);
        }
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(" AND ");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trader", textBox2.Text);
            sb.Append("TraderName  LIKE '%@Trader%' ");
        }

        command.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        bs.Filter = command.CommandText.ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Comment: First things first, a `DataGridView` is not a `DataGrid`. They are two different things, although similar. With so many similar and similarly named things in this domain, accurate terminology is important. It hasn't this time but, on another occasion, using the wrong name for something may end up wasting a lot of time on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Furthermore, the question has nothing at all to do with the grid anyway. You're asking about ADO.NET code. The fact that the data happens to be displayed in a grid is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Presumably you want something more like `"TraderName  LIKE '%' + @Trader + '%'"` that the parameter actual does what you intended. I assume that to be safe then but someone might have something to add on the injection problem.

Comment: Do you actually have a DB you work against? This shows only a command no connection to anything. You try to filter via a BindingSource but that one does not know anything about  sql therefor anything about sql injection does not  apply as it does not use sql. And your recursive (it seems) usage of the DataSource between the BindingSource and the DataGridView does also make no sense to me.

Comment: I clearly didn't read your code carefully enough because it makes no sense as it is. If you want to query the database and filter that query then use a command, actually execute it and then bind the results to your grid via a `BindingSource`. If you just want to filter locally then you should already have bound the data to the grid via the `BindingSource` and then SQL injection is not an issue. The `Filter` is just a `WHERE` clause so can't modify any data, local or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```cs
sb.Append("DealClassification LIKE '%@Deal%' ");
```

Anything inside the single quotes is literal text, so you're not even using a parameter there at all. Think about how parameters and quotes work in C# code. If you did this:

```cs
private void DisplayText(string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine("text");
}
```

would you expect the value of the `text` parameter to be display or just the word "text". Hopefully you understand it's the latter, so why should SQL be any different?

You have two choices here. You can either keep the wildcards in the SQL code and actually use the parameter:

```cs
sb.Append("DealClassification LIKE '%' + @Deal + '%' ");
```

The other option is to incorporate the wildcards into the parameter value:

```cs
sb.Append("DealClassification LIKE @Deal ");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deal", $"%{textBox1.Text}%");
```

Comment: System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [@Trader].'

Comment: Presumably you still do `bs.Filter = command.CommandText.ToString();`. A BindingSource does not know anything about Sql and your Sql Backend. It has its own syntax for local filtering. You need to actually execute your command then whats shown here should work.

Comment: @TomislavMuic, do you want to query the database or filter the data you already have? I didn't notice that you were trying to do a bit of both. Make up your mind and make it clear which you're trying to do. This answer is relevant if you want to query the database. If you just want to filter locally then get rid of all the ADO.NET code there. In that case SQL injection isn't an issue because the `Filter` property is just a `WHERE` clause so can't actually modify anything anyway.